# Mix template and non-template visitor methods

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

Currently I am learning about the Visitor Pattern and try out various ideas. 
Below I have the code of my current setup, which I would like to get functioning somehow.

I would like to have two visitors, one that counts instances of `Red` and `Blu` separately and one that counts anything (one can assume, it's a `Color`)

This is of course solvable by simply implementing the second visitor analogously to the first one, however not using separate variables for counting, but just one. 
I think however this is unnecessary - if I had for example many, many different colours, the code would be very repetitive: All functions in that visitor would be same, they would simply increment one variable. Surely, there is an easier way, but how?
According to the standard Visitor Pattern I have to implement for every color class a visit functions, thus this does not seem to be the right approach.

How would someone solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>

class Color
{
public:
    virtual void accept(class Visitor*) = 0;
};

class Red: public Color
{
public:
    /*virtual*/
    void accept(Visitor*);
    void eye()
    {
        std::cout << "Red::eye\n";
    }
};
class Blu: public Color
{
public:
    /*virtual*/
    void accept(Visitor*);
    void sky()
    {
        std::cout << "Blu::sky\n";
    }
};

class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Red*) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Blu*) = 0;
};

class CountVisitor: public Visitor
{
public:
    CountVisitor()
    {
        m_num_red = m_num_blu = 0;
    }
    /*virtual*/
    void visit(Red*)
    {
        ++m_num_red;
    }
    /*virtual*/void visit(Blu*)
    {
        ++m_num_blu;
    }
    void report_num()
    {
        std::cout << "Reds " << m_num_red << ", Blus " << m_num_blu << '\n';
    }
private:
    int m_num_red, m_num_blu;
};

class TemplateVisitor: public Visitor
{
public:
    TemplateVisitor() : num_of_colours(0) {}

    /*virtual*/
    template<class C>
    void visit(C* c)
    {
        ++num_of_colours;
    }
    void report_num()
    {
        std::cout << "Colours " << num_of_colours << '\n';
    }

private:
    int num_of_colours;

};


void Red::accept(Visitor *v)
{
    v->visit(this);
}

void Blu::accept(Visitor *v)
{
    v->visit(this);
}

int main()
{
    Color *set[] =
    {
        new Red, new Blu, new Blu, new Red, new Red, nullptr
    };
    CountVisitor count_operation;
    TemplateVisitor template_visitor;
    for (int i = 0; set[i]; i++)
    {
        set[i]->accept(&count_operation);
        set[i]->accept(&template_visitor);
    }
    count_operation.report_num();
    template_visitor.report_num();
}
```

Comment: if it seems like not the right approach then maybe it is not the right approach. Why do you use the visitor pattern in the first place? What do you actually want to achieve? No offense, but I cannot make any sense of `Red` and `Blue` being subclasses of `Color` or them having methods `sky` and `eye`...

Comment: I would like to define new operations for these classes without changing the classes. Thus using the visitor pattern made sense to me.

Comment: Just a note `template` methods cannot be virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, virtual methods and template methods can't match.

I mean... if your base class `Visitor` require

```
virtual void visit(Red*) = 0;
virtual void visit(Blu*) = 0;
```

the implementation of two virtual methods in derived classes, you can't solve this obligation with a single template method

```
template<class C>
void visit(C* c)
{
    ++num_of_colours;
}
```

You have to write two methods, absolutely not template, with the exact signature. Maybe adding also `override`, to reduce the risk of mistakes.

```
  void visit (Red * r) override
   { ++num_of_colours; }

  void visit (Blu * b) override
   { ++num_of_colours; }
```

Obviously you can define a template method (maybe with another name, but also `visit()` if you want) that is called by both virtual overrided methods

```
  template <typename C>
  void visit (C * c)
   { ++num_of_colours; }

  void visit (Red * r) override
   { visit<Red>(r); }

  void visit (Blu * b) override
   { visit<Blu>(b); }
```

This way, you can implement the logic of the visitor in a single template method and call it by all virtual methods

Comment: I am wondering now, if it were also possible to refractor all the visit override methods as their only purpose is to call the template visit method. But I guess, then would have to use another pattern. The virtual void visit really seems like a curse and blessing here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a map and add some function to color to use as an identifier?

```
class Color
{    
public:
    virtual void accept(class Visitor*) = 0;
    virtual std::string color_name() = 0; 

};

class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Color* c);
};

class CountVisitor: public Visitor
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map; 

public:
    /*virtual*/
    void visit(Color* c)
    {
        map[c.color_name()]++;
    }
};
```